# How do I choose the URL for my Spring Boot webapp without port number?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, deployment, web-deployment, embedded-tomcat-8

I have production tomcat server running on 8080 port with few war files.
Now, I have created a vaadin/spring-boot jar, and I need to deploy it in that server.
I have changed the embedded port of spring-boot application to 8082. Its working fine, but the URL is showing like - **localhost:8082/statprojectdemo**.

And current requirement demands that 8082 should not be seen in the URL.
So, Is there anyway I can use the URL as **localhost:/statprojectdemo** instead of mentioning port number.

Note* - I can't use port number 8080 or 80 as my production tomcat is running on that.

Comment: only with a proxy(apache webserver) that runs on port 80

Answer (score 0):

The port number is hard part of the url. So there is no way to direct leave it.

Like Jens said, you need to set up a proxy server that listens on yoururl.com:80/statprojectdemo and communicates with that server on 8082.